# Gasless Transaction

Tags: solidity

so I have been studying solidity since the start of February and I stumbled upon gasless transaction, how do I go about it no dapp?

I already read about the signer, relayer, forwarder and the recipient but I don't really know how to go about it. most implementations I have seen so far has been the one of dapp but I want it without dapp... I need help on how to go about it. I have checked biconomy and open Zeppelin defender and I'm currently trying learn about the erc 712 and the eip 2771

Comment: Your question is too broad. Give a specific example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.